# leftbarbuttonitem does not show up in the navigation bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I've been developing an iOS app and have been having issues with using an image as the left bar button item in the navigation bar. I have attempted this in the following ways:

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backbuttonCB"];
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);
UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame];
[backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
```

The bar button never seems to display while running the app.

I then proceeded to try this other method as follows.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbuttonCB"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(methodname)];
```

This method actually worked. However, the image displayed was tinted blue and did not look like it was meant to. Changing the tint colour of this image did not help.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

EDIT: More information, if it helps. 
This is the first view in the navigation stack. The navigation stack is displayed modally i.e. there is a previous view controller and there is a modal segue between the previous view controller and the navigation controller. This is the first view in the navigation stack.

EDIT: THE PROBLEM IS FIXED. 
I think it was a bug in xcode because when I restarted xcode and tested it with an actual device instead of the emulator, it worked fine. However, still doesn't seem to work on an emulator.

Comment: Did you try setting the background image of the button?

Comment: You should initialise UIButton as `UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` Then `setFrame` and `setImage`

Comment: Both methods did not work.

Comment: Have you tried with the custom view on the navigation bar??

Comment: No, I'll try that now. I just tried using it when displayed non-modally and it runs fine. So I'm thinking it has to do with that.

Answer (score 39):

Try setting your leftBarButtonItem this way. While presenting modally it doesn't shows up.

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem =`

Comment: This works, but why?

Answer (score 14):

Calling `myButton.sizeToFit()` before assigning to `leftBarButtonItem` helped me.

```
    let cancelButton = UIButton()
    cancelButton.backgroundColor = .red
    cancelButton.setTitle("Common/Cancel".localized, for: .normal)
    cancelButton.sizeToFit() //!!!
    let cancelBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cancelButton)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBarButton
```

Comment: My leftBarButtonItem was not showing on iOS10 and earlier. Your solution worked because I set UIEdgeInset to a negative number (for iOS11), which iOS10 didn't like. Thanks.

Comment: It helps me when device is iPhone 5 size, thank you so much !

Comment: How can you do "Common/Cancel".localized?

Comment: It's my custom extension to String:

`extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
    }`
@FrancescoLeoni

Answer (score 7):

Try to use this code,

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;

UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"];
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,buttonImage.size.width,buttonImage.size.height);
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I'm guessing it has something to do with the navigation controller being presented modally. I've added more to the question

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. To see the button, I had to change the tint color, here's the code in Swift:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(image:UIImage.init(named: "btn_back_default")!, style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("back"))
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated for Swift 5:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "iconClose")
let button = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancel))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem on iOS 13 was due to the use of the native Apple SF Symbols as the image of the UIBarButtonItem.

My advice would be to use add your image to the assets or if you prefer using SF Symbols use the "#available" selector to used them in versions > iOS 14.0, see:

```
var img: UIImage
var backButton: UIBarButtonItem

if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    img = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.backward")!
    backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(foo))
} else {
    // add your image to the project's assets first and make sure that the name is the same
    img = UIImage(named: "my-custom-image")!
    backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(foo))
}

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Comment: Yup for me also this was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code to initialize the button as a `customType` like this:

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButtonCB"];
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);
    UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backButton setFrame:buttonFrame];
    [backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
```

Hope it helps....:)

Comment: then first check your `backButtonImage` exist or not ?

Comment: The image name is correct. Like I said, when I do it as per the second method, the image is displayed but with a blue tint.

Comment: In the second method you are using @"backbuttonCB" while in first is @"backButtonCB"......"B" is the difference

Comment: That was a typo on in the stack overflow question, actually. Just fixed it.

Comment: Even your first method works at my end without any change.......according to me you should change the image & image name

Comment: It just worked when I didn't display the navigation controller modally. I think it might be something else with my project.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Navigation Item to the Views storyboard and create an outlet for it in the ViewController. Then, use your outlet instead of `self.navigationController?.navigationItem` to reference leftBarButtonItem.