# Swift Storyboard - how to not present modally

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue

I am checking to see if user logged in or is already logged in. If they are, I implement this code:

```
                        //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LogInToTagsy", sender: nil)
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tabBarController")

                        self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

I tried the commented out line as well. (and had a segue of kind "show" in storyboard).
Both options are presenting modally. I do not want this. How do I present normally?

I also have tried embedding in a navigation controller, and it gave me two nav bars for all screens. Let me know if you need more info, thank you. [image: storyboard screenshot]

[image: When embedded in Nav Controller]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `controller` from which you are calling the `show()` code should be `navigation controller` thats how you can achieve normal push instead of `modally present`. So in your case either you are calling this code from first tap bar item controller or second items `controller` ... that `controller` should be embed in `navigation`

And instead of `self.show(vc, sender: nil)` it should be

```
self.navigationController?.show(vc, sender: nil)
```

Comment: ok thanks. That's how I originally had it. But again, I have an extra nav bar when I do that (or my nav bar is pushed down). added a photo of it. I have one of my tabs in a nav controller as well.

Comment: well you should show controller instead of NavigationController ... its redundant  and of no use if you want to push Navigation controller from Navigation controller... it will present it modally if next controller is embedded in Navigation ... it should be only controller :)

Comment: ok so that works but now my nav bar buttons and title are gone. I tried to add them back programmatically and in storyboard

Comment: where you add them programmatically?

Comment: ```navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: accountButton, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goToAccount))``` in the vc that log in goes to

Comment: so button did not appear ?

Comment: i think back button is appearing instead of that bar item

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092988/leftbarbuttonitem-does-not-show-up-in-the-navigation-bar ... you need to hide backitem

Comment: ```navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true``` is right above that

Comment: use `self.navigationController?.navigationItem` instead `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`

Comment: thanks for the help. If you think my nav bar problem is unrelated to the original question, I will accept your answer and start a new question for this. Either way, I will accept your original answer.

Comment: yeah .. you can post another question ... with details about nav bar ... what you have tried ... and what you expect

Comment: Just fixed it - I just had to hide the first nav bar!